# Почему повторяется строка при использовании метода trim()

Tags: java

Не совсем понятно, почему некоторые строки повторяются по несколько раз. Объясните, пожалуйста.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "Мама мыла раму";

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println(s.substring(i).trim());
    }
}
```

И вывод будет таким:

- Мама мыла раму
- ама мыла раму
- ма мыла раму
- а мыла раму
- мыла раму
- мыла раму
- ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При переборе в начале ты попадаешь на пробел, потом на букву "М", но обе строки выглядят одинаково т.к. .trim() обрезает пробелы по краям.

Comment: Спасибо, действительно не учёл пробелы

Answer (score 2):

Возможно, короткий пример будет наглядным

```
"Мама мыла раму".trim().equals(" Мама мыла раму".trim()); // true
```

Это происходит потому, что метод trim() убирает пробелы в начала и конце строки. И соответствнно строка `" Мама мыла раму".trim()` преобразуется в `"Мама мыла раму"`